# Different value_options in Form Collection

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I hava a Collection, in which a field User (a multiselect) depends on a previous Select, the Department. Therefore each User select contain a different "value_options".

How can I set different "value_options"  when retrieving the form for each row of the Collection?

Comment: The answer is that you can't.
`value_options` is set server-side, while what you want to do is done client-side. You'll have to create the multiselect with all elements, and disable them depending on the previous select.

Comment: In Ajax (for example with jQuery) you run a query to get value_options. So you have to write a controller that processes Ajax requests

Comment: You can't just change in the front-end as you'll get Haystack Validation problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options:

- You create an API endpoint to retrieve form options
- You make this into two different pages, the first one you choose the department and the second one you choose the user (ew)
- You populate the form in server-side and you filter the selects on client side

I personally discourage the second option. Is there just to say that it is a possible solution, but **NO**.

The first option, the API, is interesting, but requires actually more work, especially if it is the only endpoint in your application.

The third option is the one I always use, since it requires the less code and it quite simple to implement.

In your form, you have your two elements:

```php
$this->add([
    'name' => 'department_id',
    'type' => 'Select',
    'attributes' => [
        'id' => 'department_id'
    ],
    'options' => [
        'value_options' => [
            1 => 'Marketing',
            2 => 'IT',
            3 => 'Logistic'
        ]
    ]
]);

$this->add([
    'name' => 'user_id',
    'type' => 'Select',
    'attributes' => [
        'id' => 'user_id',
        'multiple' => true
    ],
    'options' => [
        'value_options' => [
            [
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => 'John Doe - Marketing',
                'attributes' => ['data-department-id' => 1]
            ],
            [
                'value' => 2,
                'label' => 'Jane Doe - Marketing',
                'attributes' => ['data-department-id' => 1]
            ],
            [
                'value' => 3,
                'label' => 'Jack Doe - IT',
                'attributes' => ['data-department-id' => 2]
            ],
            [
                'value' => 4,
                'label' => 'Dana Doe - IT',
                'attributes' => ['data-department-id' => 2]
            ],
            [
                'value' => 5,
                'label' => 'Frank Doe - Logistic',
                'attributes' => ['data-department-id' => 3]
            ],
            [
                'value' => 6,
                'label' => 'Lara Doe - Logistic',
                'attributes' => ['data-department-id' => 3]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

As you can see, all the users are put in the `value_options`. Keep in mind that this is just an example, you should use custom elements to populate this kind of selects ;)

Then, in your view, you render the elements:

```php
<?= $this->formElement($this->form->get('department_id')); ?>
<?= $this->formElement($this->form->get('user_id')); ?>
```

And you finally add the JS code to handle the filter. Here I use `jQuery`, but it's not necessary to use it:

```js
$(function () {
    // Filter users when you load the page
    filterUsers(false);
    // Filter users when you change value on multiselect
    $('#department_id').on('change', function () {
        filterUsers(true);
    });
});
function filterUsers(resetValue) {
    var departmentId = $('#department_id').val();
    // Remove previous value only when filter is changed
    if (resetValue) {
        $('#user_id').val(null);
    }
    // Disable all options
    $('#user_id option').attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('hidden', true);
    // Enable only those that respect the criteria
    $('#user_id option[data-department-id=' + departmentId + ']').attr('disabled', false).attr('hidden', false);
}
```

**Final tip**: don't forget to create and add to the form a `Validator` to check the couple `department_id - user_id` is correct, just to avoid (on my example) to accept *Lara Doe* (logistic) with *IT* department ;)